# hide all duplicate div on page load using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page is showing Exception message several times  Like this:[image]

So, what i want is on page load if this below div is showing more than once then discard other & show only one message at a time...

```
        <div style="width: 70%;text-align: left;margin-left: 15%;" class="alert alert-warning text-center alert-dismissible server-side-msg text-capitalize" role="alert">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>
              <strong>We apologize for the inconvenience,An exception occured,We will solve this issue asap...
              </strong>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        </div>
```

so how to hide/remove all duplicates div for showing only one message at a time using jquery?

Comment: Instead of hiding the duplicates, you should investigate why they are replicating. Knowing the root cause is more important than finding out a work around.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Thanks for your suggestion! I already tried  but  could not able to find out & solve that issue... basically if 4 exception occures then this message will come for 4 times, if 2 exception then 2t imes....

Comment: If you could share your code which is displaying the error messages on the page, we may be be able to help you in a better way.

Comment: @Sundara why not save all erros/exceptions in one all_errors array (if it possible) and then iterate through within only one alert...so you'll get only one alert-dialog with (a <ul>-list) of all errors accured ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : select all `div` with `role="alert"` and hide them all but first one. You can use class selector also like `$('div[class="alert"]')`

```
$(function(){
 // hide all alert but the first one
 $('div[role="alert"]').not(':first').hide();
});
```

Comment: 1 more thing: first i want to check where this div present on the ui or not , if present then your code goes inside it ..and also i implemented your code but first its showing all 4 message then after its hiding all three. i want to hide all other duplicate at once

Comment: put `if($('div[role="alert"]').length>0)` condition

Comment: i implemented your code but first its showing all 4 message then after its hiding all three. i want to hide all other duplicate at once

Comment: you can do one thing, add `display:none` in your `.alert` css class and replcase query with `$('div[role="alert"]:first').show();` inside if condition. This will work definitely.

Answer (score 1):

please try this code :

```
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("divID").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var duplicated = {}, classname;
$('div').each(function() {
    classname = $(this).attr('class');
    duplicated[classname] = (duplicated[classname] | 0) + 1
})

for (var key in duplicated) {
    if (duplicated.hasOwnProperty(key) && duplicated[key] > 1) {
        $('div.' + key).slice(1).hide()
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/chankeypathak/pen/sxwCj)

PS: The above method removes duplicate `div` based on `class`, you can modify it to include `id` also.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty obvious that the all alerts are bootstrap's alert-dialogs, so the javascript( jQuery ) solution looks like this:

```
$(function() {

  //find all !visible! alert dialogs except the !last!! one and hide them..
  $('.alert:visible').not(':last').hide();
  //..you can also completely remove them from page, to avoid unnecessary DOM polution
  // please notice, that you will select ALL alerts, not only the visible ones...
  // $('.alert').not(':last').remove();
});
```

### but you also should find out, why the server renders more then one alert on the page.

more efficient solution would be one with the context, like this:

```
$('#some-elem-with-all-alerts').find('.alert:visible').not(':last').hide();
```

Comment: yeah i know why, because i have 4 diffrent exceptioon generated from the same url on page load